# What impact does saving Brick have?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

During *The Pickup* - one of the early missions in the game, you are tasked with collecting a Flathead robot from a Maelstrom hideout in an All Foods building.

Upon arriving you are told that Brick - the supposed leader of the Maelstrom gang - has been overthrown by Royce and that now you have to deal with him. On the way out after completing the deal you can find Brick in a cupboard held captive with a trip mine and you have the option to save him or leave him there.

What impact does saving Brick have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Depending on how you handled this quest a future quest will play out differently. In the sidequest, Second Conflict, both the main crew from Maelstrom or Brick himself will appear to V again as friends.
>
> If you end things with Dum Dum and Royce peacefully, and they survive the Militech encounter, then they will appear during this quest, remembering the events of The Pickup.
>
> If Dum Dum or Royce dies, or you ended things with them on negative terms, and Brick escapes the All Foods warehouse, then Brick will instead accompany you during Second Conflict. Having Brick on your side for this mission will give you more options for how to resolve it - he's a better talker than Dum Dum or Royce.
>
> Of course, you can potentially let all of the above characters die here, and then the Second Conflict mission will have an entirely different character accompany you, one not seen in this quest at all, and will give you far fewer dialogue options for this quest later.

[Source](https://www.thegamer.com/cyberpunk-2077-quest-the-pickup-how-to-save-brick-for-a-later-partnership/#:%7E:text=Saving%20Brick%20From%20All%20Foods%20In%20Cyberpunk%202077&text=In%20the%20Northern%20corner%20of,the%20Remote%20Deactivation%20hack%20option.)